# Parsing output from a function using the Python module, BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, csv, beautifulsoup

I've written the below script which takes a csv file containing a list of codes all of which form part of a URL for a webpage. It then opens each webpage, scans it for a PUBMED ID (an 8 digit number) and returns each PUBMED ID that it finds, seperated from the code that completed URL by a comma so it can be written to a CSV file:

```
import csv
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def get_PMID(y):
        url = 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/' + y + '&display=xml'
        project_page = urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(project_page, "html.parser")
        page_text = soup.text
        PUBMED_TF = bool(re.findall('PUBMED', page_text))
        if PUBMED_TF is True:
            for x in soup.find_all('db', text='PUBMED'):
                PUBMED = (x.fetchNextSiblings()[0].text)
                print PUBMED + ',' + y
        else:
            return y

with open('/Users/bj5/Desktop/web_scrape_test.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    for row in reader:
        study_accession = row[0] 
        get_PMID(study_accession)
```

In this format the output looks like this which is exactly what I want:

```
25961941,PRJEB3215
25909750,PRJEB3215
26974227,PRJEB3215
27331909,PRJEB3215
25038069,PRJEB2705
25480686,PRJEB2340
```

My problem is that I don't want to print the outuput from the function I just want to return it so I can parse it to another function. However when I try to do this by removing the print command from the function and replacing it with return I am losing part of the output. See below:

```
import csv
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def get_PMID(y):
        url = 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/' + y + '&display=xml'
        project_page = urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(project_page, "html.parser")
        page_text = soup.text
        PUBMED_TF = bool(re.findall('PUBMED', page_text))
        if PUBMED_TF is True:
            for x in soup.find_all('db', text='PUBMED'):
                PUBMED = (x.fetchNextSiblings()[0].text)
                return PUBMED + ',' + y
        else:
            return y

with open('/Users/bj5/Desktop/web_scrape_test.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    for row in reader:
        study_accession = row[0] 
        print get_PMID(study_accession)
```

gives:

```
25961941,PRJEB3215
25038069,PRJEB2705
25480686,PRJEB2340
```

I'm losing all but the first PUBMED ID from each page.

Can anyone tell me why this and how I can correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the `return` statement interrupts the function, returning the value. Thus, you are interrupting your `for x in soup.find_all('db', text='PUBMED'):` loop, returning only the value obtained in the first iteration for each call of `get_PMID`.

Consider instead storing your results into a `list` and returning the list in the end.

```
def get_PMID(y):
    # Initialize list of results
    result = []

    url = 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/' + y + '&display=xml'
    project_page = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(project_page, "html.parser")
    page_text = soup.text
    PUBMED_TF = bool(re.findall('PUBMED', page_text))
    if PUBMED_TF is True:
        for x in soup.find_all('db', text='PUBMED'):
            PUBMED = (x.fetchNextSiblings()[0].text)

            # Store each result found
            result.append(PUBMED + ',' + y)

        # Loop finished, now is the time to return the list of results
        return result
    else:
        return y
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that actually didn't quite work for me though. I guess because the return statement is still inside the loop but using a list was definitely what I needed to do, I just appended the output of both the if and else statements to the list and then returned the list outside of the loop.